# How to bake detail from high poly human to low poly human

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am struggling to find 2.8+ information around how to turn a high poly human into a low poly human whilst preserving the detail through CYCLES normal map baking. I am encountering the following issues:

- Do I retopologize with *Remesh* or *Decimate* or *Manual Retopology*?
- How do I preserve my *texture mapping* from my high poly model to low poly model?
- What happens to my *seams* after I retopologize?

How would you recommend I approach these sorts of problems?

Comment: if you want a correct topology it will have to be manual / You can bake a texture from a high-poly to a low-poly / What seams are you talking about? If you're talking about the high-poly seams they can't be transfered to the low-poly, you need to create seams on the low-poly itself if you need seams

Comment: @moonboots I love how many perfect answers I'm seeing from you :)

Comment: @Nathan, thanks, great to know that you approve  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want a correct topology (a topology that can be used for animation for example) it will have to be manual
- You can bake a texture from a high-poly to a low-poly (type "bake diffuse" in a search engine)
- If you're talking about the high-poly seams they can't be transfered to the low-poly, you need to create seams on the low-poly itself if you need seams